# Prove by Induction -Inductive Step problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The question is prove by induction that $2^n\le n!$ for all $n\ge 4$
So far I have completed the base case so,

Base case

$n=4$

$ 2^4\le4!$

$16\le24$

Therefore the base case holds

Inductive Step
Assume F(n) is true

$2^{n+1}\le (n+1)!$

$2^{n+1}\le n!(n+1)$

$2\cdot 2^n \le n!(n+1)$ <- I don’t know what do after this to get

New Approach

$2\cdot n!\le n!(n+1)$   $ by F(n) $

$2^{n+1}\le (n+1)!$

Comment: I have looked at the second answer the one with 12 votes and i dont seem to understand anything after the second line in the inductive step `$2^{k+1}<2(k!)$ `

Comment: is the new approach correct ?

Comment: in my initial question, i have added more steps. I am not that familiar with induction when it comes to inequalities so i dont get why there is nothing on the left handside for Daniel W Farlow's answer

Answer (score 1):

When $n\geqslant 4$ by assumption we have
$$2^n \leqslant n! $$
Let's multiply both sides on $2$, which gives

$$ 2^{n+1} \leqslant 2 \cdot n!\quad(1)$$
now, knowing, that for $n\geqslant 4$ we have $2 \lt n+1$, we obtain

$$2 \cdot n! \lt (n+1) \cdot n! = (n+1)! \quad(2)$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ together gives $ 2^{n+1} \lt (n+1)!$.

Comment: Could you please write it in a more comprehensible way

Comment: Of course. Which  part of the transformation you are doubt in?

Comment: in your second inequality so 2*n!<(n+1)n! how does it show it 2^(n+1)<=(n+1)!

Comment: Write in separate steps. Write if/when something seems unclear.

Comment: ahh i see thanks it makes more sense now. did you just replace RHS of (1) in (2)

Comment: Yes. We can look at it as in $2 \lt n+1$ we multiply both sides on $n!$.